# how to create a flutter app like wikipedia

Tags: ios, flutter, wikipedia, wiki, search-suggestion

I'm trying to create a Flutter app like wikipedia where a user can search and display the information but I'm don't have a lot of backend knowledge so it'll be appreciated if someone can guide me what I should do or learn in order to start this project.

The reason I'm trying to build this app is for my ethnic group. I want to have an app where we can read articles/information in our own language.

My goals is basically get all the article or documents about our cultures from other people and store in one database and display it in my app.

I'm not really sure where will be the best place to store all the article and retrieve that in Flutter. I've been looking Firebase but I'm not really sure if I can store the whole articles and display it.

Just to give you an idea, this is minipedia app and I'm thinking about creating an app just like this.

[image]

Any suggestion will be really helpful. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use Firebase Firestore for this project. I've used FB before and to the best of my knowledge, there shouldn't be any problem with doing what you mentioned above.

> I've been looking Firebase but I'm not really sure if I can store the whole articles and display it.

Yes, you can store whole articles on Firestore and retrieve them whenever you need them. Each document has a maximum limit of 1MB, which is approximately 1 million characters but should you need more space(which I highly doubt), you can always separate your articles into chunks.